# Changing JavaScript to jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I found [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-V3-API-Calculate-distance-between-two-addresses-points-locations.aspx) tutorial about adding a map that calculates the distance between two positions. It works great.
The problem here is that it's written in raw JavaScript, not jQuery.

When I include jQuery and change for example "`document.getElementById('txtSource')`" by "`$('#txtSource')`" it won't work.

Here is the original code: http://pastebin.com/BKqgYWEw

Here is my edited code: http://pastebin.com/ZrK7cSAb

Any suggestions here?

Thanks.

Comment: What did not work ? How could one make guesses about it without actually going through your code ?

Comment: Did you included jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Rayon ok I will include the whole code

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like @ssube said: You were passing a jquery object not a DOM node. I tried to accomplish what you wanted by traversing the DOM with JQuery objects and also passing the right DOM node elements to the API. Please refer to the working solution below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var source, destination;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox($('#txtSource').get(0));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox($('#txtDestination').get(0));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: mumbai
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($('#dvMap').get(0), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel($('#dvPanel').get(0));

            //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
            source = $('#txtSource').val();
            destination = $('#txtDestination').val();

            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                    var dvDistance = $('#dvDistance');
                    dvDistance.html('');
                    dvDistance.html('Distance: ' + distance + '<br>');
                    dvDistance.html('Duration:' + duration);

                } else {
                    alert('Unable to find the distance via road.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Source:
                <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="Bandra, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Destination:
                <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="Andheri, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is little problem here, the autocomplete for source and destination doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I just fixed it, please run the code again. Feel free to mark this question answered =)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors and DOM elements are not the same thing. You simply can't pass a selector like that. However, you can fetch the element from the selector using the [`get` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').constructor, $('#test').constructor, $('#test').get(0).constructor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```